# Activity has leaked window com.android and An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-2.0-eclair

When I run my script to login or register with php mysql, I got the error as given below.

```
com.example.kalyan E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40553a0
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{37f55bd V.E...... R....... 0,0-840,1132} that was originally added here
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                       at com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old.showRegisterDialog(LoginActivity_old.java:233)
                                                                       at com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old.onClick(LoginActivity_old.java:172)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-08 14:00:03.245 16742-16782/com.example.kalyan E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40571d0
07-08 14:00:03.247 16742-16742/com.example.kalyan E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{68547b2 V.E...... R....... 0,0-1026,252} that was originally added here
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                       at com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old$Registration.onPreExecute(LoginActivity_old.java:329)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
                                                                       at com.example.kalyan.LoginActivity_old$1.onClick(LoginActivity_old.java:206)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-08 14:00:03.252 16742-16782/com.example.kalyan E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4057160
07-08 14:00:04.002 16742-16778/com.example.kalyan I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
07-08 14:00:04.896 16742-16814/com.example.kalyan I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16742 SIG: 9
```

thanks guys.

My code is:

```
public class LoginActivity_old extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


Button submitBtn, registerBtn, forgotpassBtn;
EditText emailEt, passwordEt;
//SessionManager session;


//Driver Login Fields
EditText drloginEmail;
EditText drloginPassword;
TextView drloginResult;
Button loginSubmitBtn;

//Registration Fields
EditText registrationName, registrationEmail, registrationPhone, registrationPassword, registrationConfirmPassword;
TextView registrationResult;

//LostPass Fields
EditText lostPassEmail;
TextView lostPassResltText;

SharedPreferences sh;

JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();


private static final String regiURL = "http://10.0.2.2/appslider/registration.php";
public static final String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/appslider/login.php";
public static final String getDataURL = null;
public static final String recoverPasswordURL = "http://10.0.2.2/sendmail.php";



Context con;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

    con = LoginActivity_old.this;

    sh = getSharedPreferences("CRUZER_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    init();

    String email = sh.getString("loginemail", null);
    String pass = sh.getString("loginpass", null);
    boolean driver = sh.getBoolean("type", false);

    if (email != null && pass != null && !driver) {
        emailEt.setText(email);
        passwordEt.setText(pass);
        submitBtn.performClick();
    } else if (email != null && pass != null && driver) {
        showDriverLoginDialog();
        drloginEmail.setText(email);
        drloginPassword.setText(pass);
        loginSubmitBtn.performClick();
    }

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

private void init() {

    submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginSubmitBtn);
    registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginRegisterBtn);
    forgotpassBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginForgotPassBtn);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    forgotpassBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    emailEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmailEt);
    passwordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassEt);

}

//@Override
//public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
//  return true;
//}

//@Override
//public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

//  switch (item.getItemId()) {
//      case R.id.driverloginmenu:
//          showDriverLoginDialog();
//          break;
//  }

//  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

//}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!Util.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {
        Util.showNoInternetDialog(this);
        return;
    }

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.loginSubmitBtn:
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEt.getText().toString())) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordEt.getText().toString())) {
                    new Login().execute("client");
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.loginRegisterBtn:
            showRegisterDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.loginForgotPassBtn:
            showLostPasswordDialog();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And this is login code for reference. Thanks.

Comment: add ur code sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Answer (score 0):

The code line causing the error is not in this Activity class. It is in Your AsyncTask Class. Check that you are not opening a dialog after you have exited an activity. This is a common problem for newbies. You just need to take care of the context of the dialog you are about to show.

Comment: hi thanks for ur info. please tell me more about this. i couln't understood fully. how to fix this issue.how to fix this error. thanks

Comment: You can do two things,  post the code for asynctask classes also here or mail me ur code at r.doleyz1993@gmail.com. I will fix it and send u back the code along with explanations..

Comment: hi sir, really sorry for delay reply. i have email my files. pls fix this issue asap. thank u sir